# Arithmetic Progression modulo cycle detection

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Let's say I have an arithmetic series with first element a>0 and common difference d >= 0. So the series is like:
$$a + (a+d) + (a+2d) + ....$$

Now I want a series from the above:
$$ a  + (a+d)  + (a+2d) + ... \pmod{M}$$
where M > 0 and M < 100

Now the question is: what will be length of cycle in modified series? Is the cycle always possible? If yes, why?

Comment: Rehman you can apply $\mod M$ to the individual terms of the series. Hope this helps.

Comment: I will do as you said. But I want to know when a value will repeat? Is there any rule to this?